# pg.event.set_allowed([pg.KEYDOWN, pg.KEYUP, pg.QUIT]) pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

Getting error in this file when running the Mario game
I downloaded the code from the following link(https://github.com/Ja1r0/DQN-play-SuperMario) when trying to run the file super_mario.py, I am getting this above error(pygame.error video system not initialized).

I am using ubuntu 18.04 widget in windows10.

```
import platform

p_name = platform.system()
print(p_name)

import os
import pygame as pg
from . import tools
from . import constants as c
ORIGINAL_CAPTION = c.ORIGINAL_CAPTION

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
'''
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pg.init()
pg.event.set_allowed([pg.KEYDOWN, pg.KEYUP, pg.QUIT])
pg.display.set_caption(c.ORIGINAL_CAPTION)
SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode(c.SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
SCREEN_RECT = SCREEN.get_rect()
FONTS = tools.load_all_fonts(os.path.join("resources", "fonts"))
MUSIC = tools.load_all_music(os.path.join("resources", "music"))
GFX = tools.load_all_gfx(os.path.join("resources", "graphics"))
SFX = tools.load_all_sfx(os.path.join("resources", "sound"))
# dev env
'''
if True:#p_name == "aaa":
    import os
    import pygame as pg
    from . import tools
    from . import constants as c
    ORIGINAL_CAPTION = c.ORIGINAL_CAPTION


    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    pg.init()
    pg.event.set_allowed([pg.KEYDOWN, pg.KEYUP, pg.QUIT])
    pg.display.set_caption(c.ORIGINAL_CAPTION)
    SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode(c.SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
    SCREEN_RECT = SCREEN.get_rect()
    FONTS = tools.load_all_fonts(os.path.join("resources", "fonts"))
    MUSIC = tools.load_all_music(os.path.join("resources", "music"))
    GFX = tools.load_all_gfx(os.path.join("resources", "graphics"))
    SFX = tools.load_all_sfx(os.path.join("resources", "sound"))
# aws
else:
    import os
    # import pygame as pg
    from . import tools
    from . import constants as c

    ORIGINAL_CAPTION = c.ORIGINAL_CAPTION

    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
    os.environ["SDL_AUDIODRIVER"] = "dummy"
    import pygame as pg

    pg.init()

    pg.event.set_allowed([pg.KEYDOWN, pg.KEYUP, pg.QUIT])
    pg.display.set_caption(c.ORIGINAL_CAPTION)
    SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode(c.SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
    SCREEN_RECT = SCREEN.get_rect()
    FONTS = tools.load_all_fonts(os.path.join(current_dir, "..", "resources", "fonts"))
    MUSIC = tools.load_all_music(os.path.join(current_dir, "..",  "resources", "music"))
    GFX = tools.load_all_gfx(os.path.join(current_dir, "..",  "resources", "graphics"))
    SFX = tools.load_all_sfx(os.path.join(current_dir, "..",  "resources", "sound"))
```

Comment: I am using python3.6

Comment: Still getting the same error in windows also

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using `[the] ubuntu 18.04 widget in windows10` (I guess you're talking about the Windows Subsystem for Linux), which does not come with a video display. It's console only, unless you install an X-server like e.g. xming.

The error `video system not initialized` tells you exactly that: there's no video system that could draw a window avaiable.

So you could either try to install an X-server or run your code from within your Windows 10 installation, not the WSL.

Comment: for sound what we need to install

Comment: Still getting the error   "self.keys = pg.key.get_pressed()                                                                                    pygame.error: video system not initialized " even after installing xming. When running the program xming is opened and after 2 seconds it closing and giving the error mentioned above.